# How to force a Hazelcast (Jet) client to use a specific interface?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I'm just trying to test and improve performance with a client -> instance setup on a cluster. Interestingly it seems that the 1G network interface on the machine with the hazelcast (jet) instance is a major bottleneck.

I already configured the instance to use the 10G interface instead, which it obviously does. But the client seems to be adamant in using the 1G interface for the first connection, which seriously limits the throughput. Is there a way to enforce the usage of the 10G interface on the client side? `ClientConfig.getNetworkConfig()` doesn't seem to have a method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with hazelcast client(not Jet) where I had to force hazelcast to pick a specific interface and bind to it. To achieve this I did the following config

```
config.getNetworkConfig.getInterfaces.addInterface(XX.XX.XX.XX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this question. Jet will rely on the underlying Hazelcast Node or Client for it's connectivity details.

Setting the 'Interface' in the underlying Hazelcast configuration binds the network connection to that nic on a multi-homed server.